# C macro to get member of struct

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct structType {
    int someVal;
    int otherVal;

    // ...more members used for other purposes
} structType;

void myFunc(structType * theStruct, int theVal) {
    // Do something
}

int main()
{
    structType myStruct;
    
    myStruct.someVal = 5;
    myStruct.otherVal = 10;
    
    myFunc(&myStruct, myStruct.someVal);
    myFunc(&myStruct, myStruct.otherVal);

    return 0;
}
```

When calling `myFunc()` I need to pass both a pointer to the struct itself, and one of the values contained withing the struct.

Can I somehow make a macro so that `myFunc()` could be called something like:

```
MY_FUNC_MACRO(myStruct, someVal);
MY_FUNC_MACRO(myStruct, otherVal);
```

So that the struct pointer only needs to be typed once, and then the name of the member variable without passing the struct name once again.

I know about the stringilize macros like `#` an `##`, but afaik that only goes from literal name to string. I need to go the other way, to somehow concatenate multiple strings into one literal name.

Comment: "I need to go the other way," Why? Do you want to pass the member name as a string? I don't see any strings involved here.

Comment: Can you switch to C++?

Comment: I don't see why you would need this. It seems like you are trying to turn C into another language, which is never a good idea.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sure, it does not need to be an acutal string type, if that's not necessary. But it could be a string if that would help.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. strings would make things more coplicated

Comment: Do you know how to make a `union`? If `someval` and `otherval` are both int's and adjacent in the structure, a `union` could be declared that would allow you to address either as an element of an array... Since your function's 2nd parameter is an int, it could be the index of the particular member rather than the value of the particular member. Might make life simpler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything fancy

```
#define MY_FUNC_MACRO(A,B) (myFunc(&(A), (A).B))
```

works.

It's a little bit fragile though because `B` could be anything.

If you've got more nested structs and the middle layer is known at compile time, you can do this:

```
#define MY_FUNC_MACRO(A,B) (myFunc(&(A), (A).memberStruct.B))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are absolutely right. Although I realize I did a bit too much of a simplification in my question. What if `structType` contains another struct, in which the value I want is located? So i need to pass something like `myFunc(&myStruct, myStruct.memberStruct.someVal);` ?

Comment: @Klas-Kenny `MY_FUNC_MACRO(myStruct, memberStruct.someVal)` should just work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat as I said `B` can be anything :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's true. Better than nothing at least. But Ideally I'd like to only have to pass `someVal` into the macro, without specifying `memberStruct` (that should be in the macro).

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Ok, then move `memberStruct` to the macro?

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Added another example with the intermediate member in.

Comment: It really was that simple, that's great. Thank you all!

Comment: Only issue is that my IDE (Eclipse based) now complains about "Symbol 'someVal' could not be resolved", that's pretty annoying. Sure I can disable this check, but the warning is obviously useful to have. Maybe this wasn't such a good idea after all.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny I don't think there's anything you can do about that.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can simply use `typedef` like:

```
typedef structTypePointer *structType;
```

and the caller to function turn into:

```
myFunc(structTypePointer, myStruct.someVal);
```

or

```
myFunc(structTypePointer, structTypePointer->someVal);
```

Comment: This looks like it wouldn't work. You probably meant `typedef structType *structTypePointer;`, but then `myFunc(structTypePointer, ...);` doesn't compile, because `structTypePointer` is a type, not expression.